# request.getParameter() on submit buttons name returns always null

Tags: java, html, forms, jsp, servlets

I have a contact form in my website and I am trying to make it send an email to me. Email Sender class works fine the problem is when I try to get parameter from the form it always returns null. I tested in another simple form, the code worked but it doesnt work on my own form. This is the form from jsp file.

```html
<!-- Contact Form -->

<div class="col-md-6">
  <form id="contact" class="contact-form row" role="form" method="post">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
      <h5 class="successContent">
        <i class="fa fa-check left" style="color: #5cb45d;"></i>Your message has been sent successfully.
      </h5>
      <h5 class="errorContent" style="color: #e1534f;">
        <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle left"></i>There was a problem validating the form please check!
      </h5>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-field-wrapper">
        <input class="input-lg form-full" id="form-name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Name" required />
      </div>


    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-field-wrapper">
        <input class="input-lg form-full" id="form-email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-field-wrapper">
        <input class="input-lg form-full" id="form-subject" type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-field-wrapper">
        <textarea class="home-contact-txt-msg input-lg form-full" id="form-message" rows="7" name="message" placeholder="Your Message" required></textarea>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
      <input class="btn-contact-submit btn btn-lg btn-black" type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Message">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
</div>
<!-- Contact Form End -->
```

This is the part I need to get parameter.

```
<div class="col-md-12">
  <input class="btn-contact-submit btn btn-lg btn-black" type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Message">
</div>
```

And this is the email sending code.

```
<%
    String status = null;
    String parameter = null;

    //If request is submit, sending email.
    if (request.getParameter("submit") != null) {

        EmailSender email = new EmailSender();
        email.setMailServerProperties();

        //Email subject.
        String emailSubject = "Message from asdasd.com";
        //Email body.
        String emailBody = "";

        //If name is not empty, adding name to email body.
        if (request.getParameter("name") != null) {
            emailBody = "Sender Name: " + request.getParameter("name") + "<br>";
        }

        //If email is not empty, adding email to email body.
        if (request.getParameter("email") != null) {
            emailBody = emailBody + "Sender Email: " + request.getParameter("email") + "<br>";
        }

        //If subject is not empty, adding subject to email body.
        if (request.getParameter("subject") != null) {
            emailBody = emailBody + "Subject: " + request.getParameter("subject") + "<br>";
        }

        //If message is not empty, adding message to email body.
        if (request.getParameter("message") != null) {
            emailBody = emailBody + "Message: " + request.getParameter("message") + "<br>";
        }

        //Creating email object with emailSubject and emailBody.
        email.createEmailMessage(emailSubject, emailBody);


        /*
        try {
            //Sending email.
            email.sendEmail();          
        } catch (MessagingException me) {
            out.print(me.getMessage());         
        }
        */
        status = "Email sent.";
        parameter = request.getParameter("submit");
        out.print(status + parameter);
    } else {
        status = "Email not sent.";
        parameter = request.getParameter("submit");             
        out.print(status + parameter);
    }
%>
```

How can I make this part `(request.getParameter("submit") != null)` true when the forms submit button is clicked?

Edit: I noticed something. I can't get parameter of any field in this page, not only submit button.

Edit2: After many tries the working code started not to work. Is the problem can be related to apache tomcat? Is there any way to test this consistently without server issues.

Comment: 1. Add an action to the form tag 2. Rename the submit button from name="submit" to anything else - for example name="Submit" and change the JSP to reflect that change. NEVER call anything you might want to script name="submit" since it shadows the forms submit event

Comment: @mplungjan Tried both still not working. I think the problem is html related because when I do it on a simple form this code works fine.

Comment: You say "Email Sender class works fine" but yet please try removing all code related EmailSender or surrounding it try-catch block and check again whether work or not. Also, you can use MVC with JSP-Servlets putting java code into Servlets class.

Comment: @GurkanYesilyurt I am using spring already. I posted this way for you to read it easily. I solved the problem by unwrapping <input>'s with divs around them. I did not know this way a thing but it worked.

Answer (score -1):

Are you adding the libraries in the JSP file? Like `<%@ page import = "java.io.*,java.util.*" %>`

Comment: Yes, java code has no problem. Weirdly when I made a new form without wrapping them with divs , it worked.